# Detect all special characters (ascii codes 128 to 255) on a varchar column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, ascii

i have a table which has a `description_text` column (`NVARCHAR`) that i need to check for any special characters (from [ascii codes 128 to 255](http://www.asciitable.com/)).

What I wrote is:

```
SELECT cid as ID, description_id as "Element ID", description_text as Text, 'special characters in description_text (tbdescription)' as "Error"
FROM tbdescription d
WHERE
(
description_text LIKE '%' || CHR (129) || '%'
or description_text LIKE '%' || CHR (130) || '%'
//..and so on..//
)
```

Which does the job, but I'm sure there is more elegant way of verifying all these ascii codes without all the `or` conditions.

I use Oracle Client Version 11.1.0.6.0

Comment: As another option you could use [regexp_like()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions007.htm#i1048942) regular expression function. The `where` clause of a query would look less cluttered, but performance will most likely degrade.

Comment: You mean like: `where regexp_like(description_text, '(' || chr(128) || '|' || chr(129) || ')')` ? that still with `or` conditions. I'm looking for something that check ranges of ascii codes, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. where regexp_like(description_text, '(' || chr(128) || '-' || chr(255) || ')')

Use hiphen instead of pipe in your regular expresssion.

Comment: I've tried to check it with normal chars (`regexp_like(description_text, '(' || chr(97) || '-' || chr(122) || ')')`) to see if it returns any results, but it isn't. Can you check why ?

Comment: My bad, forgot to change `'('` to `'['`. Thanks :)